# Get null value from existing element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Script :

```
 $(document).on("click",".check",function(){   
    $(".check").each(function(){
        alert(JSON.stringify(this));
    });
 });
```

Element :

```
  <input class="check check-list" value="1" type="checkbox" name="check-obj">1
  <input class="check check-list" value="2" type="checkbox" name="check-obj">2
  <input class="check check-list" value="3" type="checkbox" name="check-obj">3
  <input class="check check-list" value="4" type="checkbox" name="check-obj">4
```

My problem is when I check the checkbox, it will only return an empty alert `"{}"`, I tried to get `this.val()` and it return `"this.val is not a function"`.
How can i get the value to display from the checkbox?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: @NickParsons currently i just want to alert all checkbox value once i click any 1 of them

Comment: do you want to get value of the checked one or value of all??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.val()` is a jQuery method and will only work on jQuery objects. So you need to wrap `this` in `$()` in order to use `.val()`:

`$(this).val()`

Alternatively, you can use `this.value` which is the vanilla javascript way of getting the `value` from an element.

Moreover, there is no need for you to use `JSON.stringify()` as `$(this).val()` (and `this.value`) will give you a string already, so what your essentially doing is turning `"1"` into `"\"1\""` (rendered as `""1""`).

See example below:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".check", function() {
  $(".check").each(function() {
    alert($(this).val()); // this.value works aswell
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="check check-list" value="1" type="checkbox" name="check-obj">1
<input class="check check-list" value="2" type="checkbox" name="check-obj">2
<input class="check check-list" value="3" type="checkbox" name="check-obj">3
<input class="check check-list" value="4" type="checkbox" name="check-obj">4
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on("click",".check",function() {
    var values=[];
    $(".check:checked").each(function(){
        values.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(values));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="check check-list" value="1" type="checkbox" name="check-obj">1
  <input class="check check-list" value="2" type="checkbox" name="check-obj">2
  <input class="check check-list" value="3" type="checkbox" name="check-obj">3
  <input class="check check-list" value="4" type="checkbox" name="check-obj">4
```

`this` as in your `JSON.stringify(this)` is each `input` element (`DOMElement`). `this.val()` doesn't exist, the `DOMElement` doesn't have such method, `val()` is a jQuery's method, thus you have to select the element with jQuery, then use `val()`: `$(this).val()`.

But `val()` will always return the *value* of the field, in your case `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`. If you're trying to see if they're checked, you'd have to check the 'checked' property. An easy way to do that with jQuery is using the `:checked` selector.

So, if your intention was to get a JSON list *of the values of the checked elements*, you would have to do something like:

```
$(document).on("click",".check",function() {
    var values=[];
    $(".check:checked").each(function(){
        values.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(values));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure js you can do it by selecting all the elements with class `.check` and than add event listener to each element.

```js
let ele = document.querySelectorAll('.check');

 ele.forEach(e=>{
  e.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log(e.target.value);
  })
 })
```

```html
<input class="check check-list" value="1" type="checkbox" name="check-obj">1
  <input class="check check-list" value="2" type="checkbox" name="check-obj">2
  <input class="check check-list" value="3" type="checkbox" name="check-obj">3
  <input class="check check-list" value="4" type="checkbox" name="check-obj">4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values of checked radio button use this

```
$('.check').off().on('click', function() {
    $('.check:checked').each(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

If what you need is value of all the checkbox then use this

```
$('.check').off().on('click', function() {
    let $this = $(this);
    $('.check').each(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```